# libGDX:Adding uniform var

Tags: opengl, shader, libgdx

I'm trying to add an uniform var to my shader , this is my shader:

```
    String vertexShader = "attribute vec4 " + ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE + ";\n" //
            + "attribute vec4 " + ShaderProgram.COLOR_ATTRIBUTE + ";\n" //
            + "attribute vec2 " + ShaderProgram.TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE + "0;\n" //
            + "uniform mat4 u_projTrans;\n" //
            + "varying vec4 v_color;\n" //
            + "varying vec2 v_texCoords;\n" //
            + "\n" //
            + "void main()\n" //
            + "{\n" //
            + "   v_texCoords = " + ShaderProgram.TEXCOORD_ATTRIBUTE + "0;\n" //
            + "   gl_Position =  u_projTrans * " + ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE + ";\n" //
            + "}\n";
        String fragmentShader = "#ifdef GL_ES\n" //
            + "#define LOWP lowp\n" //
            + "precision mediump float;\n" //
            + "#else\n" //
            + "#define LOWP \n" //
            + "#endif\n" //
            + "varying vec2 v_texCoords;\n" //
            + "uniform sampler2D u_texture;\n" //
            + "uniform sampler2D u_texturePalette;\n" //
            + "void main()\n"//
            + "{\n" //
            + " vec4 textureColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoords).rgba;\n"
            + " vec4 paletteColor = texture2D(u_texturePalette, vec2(textureColor.b,0)).rgba;\n"    
            + "  gl_FragColor = paletteColor;\n" //
            + "}";
```

The problem comes with

> uniform sampler2D u_texturePalette;

ShaderProgram doesn't recognize the new uniform in the shader. Also i have done this :

```
    shader = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    shader.setUniformi("u_texturePalette", 0);
    Texture text = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("./data/palette.png"));
    text.bind(shader.getUniformLocation("u_texturePalette"));
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    batch.setShader(shader);
```

When i call function    `shader.hasUniform("u_texturePalette")` , it resolves to true , but when i go to see `shader.getUniformLocation("u_texturePalette")` it resolves to -1

Is this a bug? . Any idea of what i'm doing bad?

Comment: Are you certain the shader compiles and links successfully?

Comment: @Tim The shader compiles well , but how can i see it links ok?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with libGDX, but with OpenGL it would be something like `glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, retVal)`. See what kind of error checking libGDX supports.

Answer (score 1):

Shader code looks fine.

Generally you do it like this:

```
shader = new ShaderProgram(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
Texture text = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("./data/palette.png"));
text.bind(0);
shader.setUniformi("u_texturePalette", 0);
```

So you bind the texture to an active texture unit and then pass that unit via `setUniformi()`.

`getUniformLocation()` does actually something different: https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetUniformLocation.xml

However you will run into some more issues here, since `SpriteBatch` internally does some very specific stuff with the custom shader. I'd recommend you take a look at the code: 
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.java

Specifically it will expect the default texture to always be at unit 0.